# Echo -e is not working in my script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am writing a program to hide the password to end user using bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e "\nEnter password:"
stty -echo
read password
stty echo
echo
echo Password read.
```

It displays the output with -e in the terminal

```
~/pgm $ ./em.sh
-e 
Enter password:
```

Instead of

```
Enter password:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POSIX [doesn't mandate `echo -e` support](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), it even forbids it, so your `/bin/sh` doesn't support it and outputs "-e" as a string instead. If you really want it you may switch to `/bin/bash` by changing the first line of your script or replace `echo` with `printf`.

Comment: It should be emphasized that POSIX doesn't just leave extra options undefined; it actually *prohibits* options other than the implementation-defined `-n`. Doing anything other than printing a literal `-e` is non-compliant behavior.